# How to combine POSIX character classes of a regex?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, posix

I need to combine different character classes in a regular expresion used by sed. I need to match `[:word:]` and the minus symbol `-`. How does that look like?  All my attempts failed at trying or searching a solution.

In the following strings I would like to match everything until the first space:

```
foo-bar     |
baz-xyz-123 |
```

Comment: Give an example of string(s) you want to match.

Comment: What is character class `[:word:]`?

Comment: @cuonglm see http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: I doubt `[:word:]` is supported in all locale.

Comment: It's not supported. Use `[[:alnum:]_-]`

Comment: Possibly relevant for BSD systems: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356234/135943

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]_-]//g'
```

will remove everything is not alpha numeric characters in your current locale, `_` and `-`.

```
$ echo 'foo-bar     |' | sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]_-]//g'
foo-bar
```

But if you want to print everything until first space:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/'
```

or `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1}'
```